# How to use RWMutex and upgrade locks

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement the pattern of access to a map that allows multiple
readers and only one writer and where the key is only written to the map once.

I want to make sure that the key, if it exists, is only ever placed into the map one time.  And then once the key is added, the readers obtain the value from the map.

It think this is correct, although the main thread could exit before all the goroutines finish, hence I don't always see 10 Exit's printed.  Is this the correct pattern of implementation?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var downloads map[string]*sync.WaitGroup
var downloadsLock sync.RWMutex

func concurrentAccessTest() {
    // Acquire the read lock to check if the items is already there.
    downloadsLock.RLock()
    if wg, ok := downloads["item"]; ok {
        // Item exists
        downloadsLock.RUnlock()
        wg.Wait()
    } else {
        downloadsLock.RUnlock()

        fmt.Println("Upgrade Lock")
        // Item does not exist we need to add it to the map
        downloadsLock.Lock()
        fmt.Println("Writer lock obtained")
        // Check another thread hasn't gone down this path and added the item to the map
        if wg, ok := downloads["item"]; ok {
            // Item exists, no need to add it, unlock and wait
            downloadsLock.Unlock()
            wg.Wait()
            fmt.Println("Ok, now we can proceed")
        } else {
            // We are first in. Add and unlock
            wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
            downloads["item"] = wg
            downloadsLock.Unlock()

            wg.Add(1)

            fmt.Println("Do some time consuming stuff!")
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Exit")
}

func main() {
    downloads = make(map[string]*sync.WaitGroup)

    // Add to the map
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go concurrentAccessTest()
    }

    concurrentAccessTest()

    // Wait for all threads to exit
    fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code shows, there's no way to upgrade from a read to a write lock, you have to release the read lock and then take the write lock.

I think you're close, the use of `RWMutex` itself looks fine, however i believe you have a potential issue with calling `wg.Add(1)` after releasing the lock. There's a chance that one of the other goroutines will read the WaitGroup out of the map and call Wait() before the call to Add() is executed, which according to the WaitGroup docs is an issue. The docs say `Note that calls with a positive delta that occur when the counter is zero must happen before a Wait.` You can easily fix this by moving the `wg.Add(1)` call before the Unlock()

Comment: Thanks.  It appears to work.  I was playing with kicking off the goroutines with a little bit of randomness as well and I'm seeing it hit all the various paths.  It's odd that you can't upgrade an RLock to a Lock as you have to RUnlock then Lock.  But other than that.

Comment: There's actually a good reason why you can't upgrade read locks to write locks, but instead have to first release the read lock. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407677 It's about pthread and not golang RWMutex, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you `defer` the `RUnlock()` call? If so, "ugrading" is more difficult: If you unlock the read lock manually to aquire the write lock the `defer` method will screw up later. That means you must read stuff (utilizing the read lock and the `defer` statement) in a seperate function.

Comment: Using different unlock functions for read lockers vs write lockers is quite annoying. The typical use case is "grab read lock, check if the thing is in the map, if not, grab write lock and put it in, now when you have the thing, read some data out to return, then unlock the lock." You can't share the "read some data out" code path without also having a flag for which unlock function to call.

Comment: Good idea, but also using defer can be expensive if not strictly needed.

Comment: What can I say? Even after all these years in Go, I feel that locks are still harder to use and more unrelyable as in, say Java. There is just no clear pattern to ensure a lock being released under all circumstances in Go, so we can have the choice between multiple, subpar actions.

Answer (score -1):

Offtop: I used to struggle with this one, wondering why this isn't possible in go. Seemed like a stupendous idea for such a cool feature to not be implemented. The answer is quite simple: if upgrading locks was possible, it'd be too easy to deadlock.

`postgres` offers this capability with `advisory_locks`. You can test the thing by yourself.

Open two terminals with `postgres` sessions and write in both of them:

```
BEGIN;
pg_advisory_xact_lock_shared(1);
```

This will acquire the shared-`read` lock. Then, we acquire the write lock in the first terminal:

```
SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(1);
```

It starts waiting for the second read lock to release - seems cool, exactly what we expect.

And now for the sweet part. Open the second terminal and try to do the same: acquire the write lock:

```
SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(1);
```

The transaction will end in error:

```
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 7421 waits for ExclusiveLock on advisory lock [26774,0,1,1]; blocked by process 7429.
Process 7429 waits for ExclusiveLock on advisory lock [26774,0,1,1]; blocked by process 7421.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
```

The cool thing about `postgres` is that we get deadlock detection out of the box. But we wouldn't in go. So your program would stop working, and you wouldn't have a clue why.